# Extract First 5 Words from String

Tags: php

I need to extract the first 5 words, allowing points, numbers and parenthesis from this string using PHP:

*Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database*

I want **Output** Like this...

*Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013)*

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: split the string on spaces using explode() and then join first five elements of the resulting array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = "Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database";
echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $string), 0, 5));
```

**Output**

```
Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013)
```

Comment: No need for the array_slice if you use a limit for explode.

Comment: @fanfavorite this is perfect answer. can you pls explain why no need of array_slice? you can check the output

Comment: You can use array_slice, but if the string it very large it will create a large array instead of an array of only 6 elements like if you did explode(' ',$string,6), then just need array_pop() to drop last one or can use array_slice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Split your string into an array of size 6. First five containing one word each, last one containing the rest.
2. Remove the last array element.
3. Put the remaining 5 array elements back together into a string.

The following code will print "Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013)".

```
$str = "Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database";
$words = explode(" ", $str, 6);
array_pop($words);
$words = implode(" ", $words);
print $words;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$inputstring = "Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database";
$firstwordsArr = explode(" ", $inputstring, 6);
array_pop($firstwordsArr);
$firstwords = implode(" ", $firstwordsArr);
echo $firstwords;
```

Comment: your code show me output like this : `Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database`

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot the explode adds the rest to last value of array.  This is fixed.

Comment: what is with the downvotes?

Comment: right answer 1 upvote from my side. and thanks for that explanation

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
$string = "Below your Eyes 3.2 (2013) Unrated From database";
$nice = substr($string, 0, 26);
echo $nice;
```

The `substr()` method is alot easier than the other answers.

PHP `substr`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: he wants 5 words not 26 characters? how can you said that it is easy method?

Comment: That's fine if the first five words always take up exactly 26 letters, but that's unlikely to be true.

Comment: Please don't vote down because if you try the code you will see that it outputs what he wants.

Comment: I was under the impression it was only for this string. That was what was implied in the question.

Comment: If he wanted to do it for exactly that string, there'd be no reason for not just doing it manually. Obviously, he wants a flexible solution that works for any string.